# Load javascript as an ES6 module OR via a script tag in the page

Tags: javascript, module, es6-modules

Fairly new to JS modules of any kind.  I have a simple vanilla JS script that is intended to be loaded into an html document via the script tag.  Basically...

```
// invoke main function when DOM is ready
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    MainFunction();
});

var MainFunction = function() {
    // check for specific DOM nodes upon invocation...
}
```

Works great.  But I'd like to also be able to make `MainFunction` available as a module export so I can import it into a webpack bundle like:

```
import MainFunction from 'myclassicscript';
```

And then I can invoke it as necessary in the main bundle with:

```
MainFunction();
```

How the same script can be used both ways. I can't seem to find any info on how to do it, but I might have totally the wrong idea.

Something like...?

```
// check if this is a browser environment...
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {

    // invoke main function when DOM is ready
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        MainFunction();
    });

}

var MainFunction = function() {
    // check for specific DOM nodes upon invocation...
}

// ???
export default MainFunction;
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong you can only add a javascript file through script tag, since `import` is an ES6 spec which hasn't been implemented yet in any browser

Comment: I'm using webpack to do the imports

Comment: @GustavoTopete [It has been, for over a year now](https://jakearchibald.com/2017/es-modules-in-browsers/)